# Why tabular integration method fails in this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried to integrate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} sin^2 (x) dx $ using tabular integration method but I ended up getting a +$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} sin^2 (x) dx $  on the right side. This caused my integral to end up 0 on the left side. I'm curious of what went worng?

Comment: It would be great if you could show your work.

Comment: @KM101 http://imgur.com/gallery/ndY6kzF

Comment: You left out an extra $+\sin(x)\cos(x)$ term. All you're left with is $\displaystyle \int \sin^2(x) \mathrm dx = \displaystyle \int \sin^2(x) \mathrm dx$, which doesn't get you anywhere. Since every row gives a positive integral, you can't isolate the integral on one side either. Tabular integration will only "work" if you get a simpler integral or isolate the integral on one side, so it doesn't work here. Instead, you need to use $\sin^2(x) = \dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$.

Comment: @KM101 Thanks. I used that identity to solve it. Is this a case where integration by parts fail?

Comment: I wouldn't say it fails, but that it isn't useful. The entire point of integration by parts is to go from a harder integral to an easier one, or isolate the original integral on one side, such as with $\displaystyle \int e^x\cos(x) \mathrm dx$. If you can't do either, it's pointless.

Comment: @KM101 OK I think I understand. Thanks 

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^2 x dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{2} (1-\cos 2x)dx=\frac{1}{2}[x-\frac{\sin 2x}{2}]_{0}^{\pi/2}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: 2 should be 4 in final answer.

Comment: Oh! yes Thanks, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use tableau to get

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^2 x dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^2 x dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}1dx - I$$ etc